# C# Parameter Attributes RegEx

Tags: c#, attributes

I was just reading The Pragmatic Programmer and the Design By Contract chapter.  It occurred to me that when we make a function maybe in a common library, specifying attributes of parameters would be a useful thing.

I'm wondering if anyone has come across such an idea, I don't believe it exists in C# quite how I'm thinking which is something like this;

```
public String SendEmail(String ToAddress [RegExMatch(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b")], FromAddress, Body)
```

For readability it would make more sense to put it above the function declaration I think.

I can't imagine it would be a bad idea as the function could automatically throw an exception for invalid parameters.  But it would just give a bit more definition than String or Int32.

More of a discussion than looking for an answer.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: What about the valid email address `a+1@a-b-c1.museum`?

Comment: A good question, but my regex was just an example.  Feel free to start a Q on the ultimate regular expression for email. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to just create a new type that deals with that kind of stuff.  You could have an EmailAddress type which validates any string arguments it gets when constructed or modified.  Then there is no need for attribute trickery.

Comment: I like this idea.  I could get it to work similar to a RegularExpressionValidator.  I think I'll take a look and make a proof.  I'll post it here when it's done.

Comment: Some (most?) DbC implementations allow static checking for at least a subset of contracts and parameters. The normal `throw new Exception();` wouldn't be amenable to that. In the end, I'd say the DbC approach *combined* with the OO approach suggested would be the most powerful - but very possibly overkill as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've ever seen a regex specifically as a contract - but it's not a far stretch from checking input ints for valid ranges, or parameters != null, etc. which are all standard fare in DbC.

C#/.NET has the official System.Diagnostics.Contracts [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx). [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) 
is a C# derived language that added DbC. I *assume* that much of .NET 4's Code Contracts came out of Spec# - so I'm not sure how much more Spec# offers at this point.

I'm not a DbC guy - but thought it might be useful to let you know; yes, folks are doing it, and yes, what you suggest is certainly feasible and reasonable (though email addresses are notoriously hard to validate with a regex - so you may want a different example).

Comment: Interesting reading thanks.  Feels abit WCF influenced. But I'll definately give it a read.  Thanks!